# How to fill missing NA's with sequence in numeric column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

Example data: `week = c(0,1,2,3,4,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,10)`

Current solution that I am using is:

```
ifelse(is.na(week),na.locf(week)+1,week)
```

But it outputs: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 10

Desired Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does your actual data look like? For this example you could use `ifelse(is.na(week), 0:9, week)`, but if you can edit your question to include a different representation of "week" it would make it easier to answer

Comment: Hi @jared-mamrot, I updated my data in question, @Ben solution using `accumulate` worked for that scenario as well.  thank you for your answer!, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `purrr` you can try the following. If missing (`NA`) then increase by 1, otherwise, keep the value.

```
library(purrr)

accumulate(week, ~ifelse(is.na(.y), .x + 1, .y))
```

**Output**

```
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Hi @Ben, I just changed my example data: `week = c(0,1,2,3,4,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,10)`,
but your answer works for that too, thanks a ton! thank you for helping!

Comment: awesome use of accumulate. +1

Answer (score 1):

The `zoo` package has a function for that specific purpose: `na.spline`.

```r
week = c(0,1,2,3,4,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,10)

zoo::na.spline(week)
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Great to know about this package , thank you!